# Concatenate these two expressions with an AND

Tags: java, expression

Bit of a weird one but I use a system at work that employs Java based placeholder language and I'm trying to put these two together - you don't really need to focus on the expressions but more the logic of the syntax, can someone help me logically add an and to both of these:

This one is looking at a table and checking todays date equals a date in a hadoop table

```
<%ForEach var="count" items="${ecx:filter(ecx:related('ecrm-one-voucher',user.CustomAttribute.StoreID), 'SendDate','==',  ecx:formatDate(ecm:addInterval(date.today, '+3d'),'yyyy-MM-dd',ecm:timeZone('Europe/London'),'',false))}"%>
```

This one checks another column for a value of Light or Heavy:

```
items="${ecx:filter(ecx:related('pizzahut', user.CustomAttribute.StoreID), 'Segment', '==', user.CustomAttribute.Segment)}" max="1"
```

I just need to add an AND so I have all the items in there because it should be checking if campaign date = today() and user segment equals light or heavy.

I appreciate that it won't be a language you know but someone will probably be able to help :)

Comment: what is this language or technogy? is there any documentation to it?

Comment: It's built in Java. I'm tryignt o find the documentation, we just changed all our systems and I've lost all my links.

I used to be able to get o to JSTL libray basically that would help.

Comment: http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/tld-summary.html

This is the framework the language uses basically

Comment: how did you finally solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%ForEach var="count" items="${ecx:filter(ecx:related('ecrm-one-voucher',user.CustomAttribute.StoreID), 'SendDate','==',  ecx:formatDate(ecm:addInterval(date.today, '+3d'),'yyyy-MM-dd',ecm:timeZone('Europe/London'),'',false),'&&',ecx:related('pizzahut', user.CustomAttribute.StoreID), 'Segment', '==', user.CustomAttribute.Segment)}"%>
```

I've simply put both expressions inside `ecx:filter` side by side with the `"&&"` argument in the middle.

Comment: Damn - unfortunately not, get this:

    Error in expression language (EL): Error parsing '${ecx:filter(ecx:related('ecrm-one-voucher',user.CustomAttribute.StoreID), 'SendDate','==', ecx:formatDate(ecm:addInterval(date.today, '+3d'),'yyyy-MM-dd',ecm:timeZone('Europe/London'),'',false) && ecx:related('pizzahut', user.CustomAttribute.StoreID), 'Segment', '==', user.CustomAttribute.Segment))}': syntax error at position 300, encountered ')', expected '}'

Comment: i've edited the code, i had there one additional `)` bracket at the end of expression, try again

Comment: Oh thanks - something different now haha - Error in expression language (EL): Error parsing '${ecx:filter(ecx:related('ecrm-one-voucher',user.CustomAttribute.StoreID), 'SendDate','==', ecx:formatDate(ecm:addInterval(date.today, '+3d'),'yyyy-MM-dd',ecm:timeZone('Europe/London'),'',false),': syntax error at position 196, encountered 'null', expected ||||'true'|'false'|'null'|'-'|'!'|'not'|'empty'|'('

Comment: hmm i've accitentally used double quotes in place of single quotes, maybe you could try again? then last thing i'm thinking of is to use `'(',expression1..,')','&&','(',expression2...,')'` inside the filter function

Comment: It's definitely closer - Error in expression language (EL): Parameters for function 'ecx:filter' do not match

Just saying that now which I'm sure of the meaning.